# Quais são as diferenças entre uma imagem e um container?

Tags: docker

Estou [lendo a respeito do Docker](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-php-application) e fiquei confuso em relação ao que seria um *container* e uma *imagem*, o entendimento de ambos não estão claros para mim.

## Perguntas

1. O que é um container no contexto do Docker?
2. O que é uma imagem no contexto do Docker?
3. Os containers e as imagens possui alguma diferença? Se sim, quais são?
4. Existe alguma dependência entre uma imagem e um container ou vice-versa?

Comment: Sabe a diferença de classe e instância no OOP?

Comment: @Woss Instancia é um objeto de uma classe na memória, classe é só a representação de algo, pelo menos na maioria das linguagens, algumas linguagens classe podem ser objetos mesmo não tendo "instancia" ;D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Uma boa analogia para o entendimento sobre imagens e containers é [essa do comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/425498/quais-s%c3%a3o-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-uma-imagem-e-um-container#comment825923_425498). A classe seria a imagem, onde você cria a definição e os comportamentos que um determinado container terá, e o container é a instância que você irá efetivamente usar durante a execução.

Sobre suas dúvidas, parte delas estão explicadas na [documentação sobre a arquitetura base do Docker](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/overview/).

[image: Arquitetura do Docker]

> O que é uma imagem no contexto do Docker?

A imagem é um template que será utilizado por seu container. Nela é definido o que vai rodar ali dentro, quais as bibliotecas e configurações estarão presentes no seu container.

As imagens são divididas no sistema de arquivos em diversas camadas somente leitura, formando uma pilha. As imagens são na maioria das vezes baseadas em outras imagens ou camadas, reaproveitando o que foi construido anteriormente. Você pode adicionar novas customizações em novas camadas e construindo a sua imagem.

Como no seu exemplo, você pode utilizar a imagem base do PHP (que por sua vez pode ser baseada numa imagem base do Debian ou Alpine) e customizá-la instalando alguma extensão ou alterando as configurações do `php.ini` a partir de um Dockerfile.

> O que é um container no contexto do Docker?

O container é a estrutura que você realmente executa. Ele é um ambiente isolado entre o sistema operacional e outros containers, no nível de processos. Isso inclui o sistemas de arquivos e recursos de rede. Os containers podem ser parados, reiniciados ou removidos, mas geralmente eles são efêmeros. É preferível criar um novo container e começar de novo ao invés de manter containers executados por muito tempo. Leia mais sobre nesse artigo [Pets vs Cattle<sup>en</sup>](https://medium.com/@Joachim8675309/devops-concepts-pets-vs-cattle-2380b5aab313).

> Existe alguma dependência entre uma imagem e um container ou vice-versa?

Não existe uma dependência obrigatória, mas geralmente você cria um novo container com base em uma imagem. Nesse processo de iniciar o container, é adicionado no topo da pilha de camadas uma camada que permite leitura e escrita para o container em execução e é criado um volume para esse container.

Você até pode iniciar um container sem nenhuma imagem base, mas você não terá nenhuma biblioteca ou comando para executar ali dentro.

Com isso, durante a execução desse container é possível os processos internos executarem normalmente, criando ou editando arquivos nesse volume isolado. Porém, nenhuma alteração é persistida nas camadas anteriores daquela imagem.

Se você criar dois containers com base na mesma imagem, eles sempre serão idênticos. É possível você persistir essa camada que permite escrita para uma camada somente leitura, mas isso geralmente é feito num `Dockerfile` para que seja possível reproduzir a mesma configuração no futuro.

> Os containers e as imagens possui alguma diferença? Se sim, quais são?

São dois conceitos diferentes, porém que são usados juntos. A principal diferença é que você não pode executar diretamente uma imagem e a mesma é por consequência somente leitura, um modelo que será utilizado por um container.

O container por sua vez permite que você execute o que está definido em uma imagem, de forma que as alterações que aconteçam em tempo de execução não são persistidas de volta na imagem base.

Outra analogia que gosto de usar é com um distribuição Linux rodando em Live CD. A ISO é a sua imagem e quando você executa o Live CD do Ubuntu, por exemplo, você pode executar o sistema sem instalá-lo no seu disco, criando novos arquivos, executando seu navegador, entre outros.

Como nos containers, você tem a opção de persistir as mudanças do seu Live CD no disco ou então encerrar sua sessão e começar do zero novamente.